# "link only" flag disappeared

Tags: support, flagging, specific-flag

In my remembering there was a (very useful) "link-only" flag for answers. This flag was basically saying that even the link could answer the question, the content of the link should be copied because the link may die and "kill" the answer on the way.

I just noticed that this flag disappeared.

Is there a good reason for that?

(or am I just completely crazy and this flag never existed?)

Comment: Related question (if not duplicate): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19818/answers-with-links-or-references

Comment: I actually use the other mod flag and write link only in these cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such flag, but there is an option like that in the Low Quality Review. All it does is insert a templated comment with the text you remembered, while casting a vote to delete the answer.

If you are flagging (rather than reviewing) something that shouldn't be an answer, consider the flags VLQ (very low quality) or NAA (not an answer). The difference in practice is small; I usually go with NAA.

Comment: Ah, thank you, so I'm not totally crazy. Ok I'll do so next time.